# Longitudinal predictive models

Tags: data-mining, predictive-models

I have a predictive model to construct and am looking for some ideas on the approach. I have a large training dataset of customers' balances (think a savings account) at time t=1 to 36 representing monthly averages over three years. I will want to construct a model to predict the value of a customer's account at t=4..36 using only information available at the end of t=3. *Hence, this is a forecasting type problem, but not in the time series sense where you observe a sequence of data significantly longer than the time horizon you are trying to predict.*

I am thinking of approaching this like a discrete hazard model, where a row in the dataset is created for every customer/month combination (so here each customer has 33 rows in the data and a variable called t takes on the values 4 to 36). Repeated for every month is the "initial state" variables for the customer known at the end of month 3. This is the setup of the so-called [person period data](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/examples/alda/ch2.htm).

I would then learn a regression model on this data using the initial state data and 't'.

There would be no accounting for the fact that the customers are repeated in the data. This works for a discrete time hazard model, but my question is if this is OK for a linear regression or a machine learning algorithm (e.g. neural net)? Is there a better way?

**ADD**: Specifically I am wondering if such a model will fail if it does not explicitly account for the repeated measures and the correlation between rows (same customers at various values of 't'). When dealing with a predictive model, how could this be accounted for?

Comment: You talk about a regression model. The regressors will be just an intercept and "time"?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I would have an intercept (assuming linear regression) and time (takes on integer values 4-36 and either a square and cubic of this variable or a natural cubic spline). I would also have predictor variables that are not time varying - these are the aspects of the account/customer known at the end of time t=3.

Comment: Discrete hazard models model failure rates over discrete units in time. I see the units in time (monthly compounded transactions and interest...) but... what's "failing" in these data? Your outcome is continuous. Are you trying to non-parametrically model time as with a baseline hazard in a Cox model?

Comment: @AdamO what I am talking about is the same data set-up as discrete time hazard models, but the outcome is continuous. I am not modeling failure here. Think of it this way, I know the amount of the account (balance) at time t=3 and i have attributes about the customer at that point in time and I am trying to predict the balance (the stream) at each time t from 4 to 36.

Comment: Hazards are instantaneous (or in this case, differential) failure risks in subjects, I don't see how you can draw predictions for continuous outcomes. Can you provide a reference for this method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is phase 1 of my answer. I want first to make sure that I understand the model.
Take just one customer, say customer $i$, and denote by $s_{it}$ its monthly savings balance. From what the OP writes, the model appears to be (for one customer and assuming linearity for the moment)

$$ s_{it} = g(a_1t,a_2t^2, a_3t^3,..) + X_{i3}\beta + u_{it},\qquad t=4,...,36$$

...where $g(b_1t,b_2t^2, b_3t^3,..)$ represents various time-variables (that enter additively), and $X_{i3}$ is the matrix including the "initial state data" (of time period $3$).
Is this an accurate depiction of the general idea? If it is I have one question and one remark:
**Question:** what happens to data from period 1,2,3? Aren't they used somehow (apart from $X_{i3}$)?

**Remark:** If all regressors in $X_{i3}$ are time-invariant, then their effect on $ s_{it}$ cannot be separated -they form a composite "intercept".

Waiting on OP's feedback.

**PHASE 2**
Given the OP's clarifications (although, I must note that it is not "for simplicity" that a *time-invariant* regressor "does not change with t"), let's explore the possible model

$$ s_{it} = \sum_{l=1}^{k}a_lt^l + X_i\beta + u_{it},\qquad t=4,...,36$$

My previous remark stands: *whatever* is in $X_i$, be it regressors specific to customer $i$, or even products of these regressors etc, or even some collective variables from periods $1,2,3$, to the degree that they are time-invariant for the time period $4,...,36$, then their effects on the dependent variable cannot be separated. Moreover $X_i$ is *known*, and if they are measured in the same units as the dependent variable, then their sum should be subtracted from the dependent variable, they do not belong in the RHS of the equation.

Moreover by a comment of OP in another answer, it appears that an assumption that customers exhibit similar behavior is made: namely, we could use some accounts to estimate the regression, and then use the estimated coefficients to predict the behavior of _other_accounts, presumably of other customers.

Taken all the above into account, we are led in a model that can be written 
$$ s_{it} - \sum_{j=1}^{m}x_{ij} = \sum_{l=0}^{k}a_lt^l + u_{it},\qquad t=4,...,36\qquad i=1,...,n$$

...where $n$ is the number of customers comprising the training sample. This model could be estimated by one of the many panel data estimators available, given also the constraints imposed by the structure of the specification. But although the panel data would permit a better estimation of the coefficients involved, the main issue remains: we are depending only on the powers of $t$ to capture the variability of the dependent variable. Personally, I don't "trust" that kind of models: they are a classic case where you could obtain a "perfect fit" by adding more and more powers of $t$ -only to find out that this "perfectly fitted" model is the worst when it comes to prediction out-of-sample.

What then? I believe that the $VARMA$ modelling (also discussed in another answer) is a better way to go: namely a *vector* autoregressive-moving average model:

$$s_{it} - \sum_{j=1}^{m}x_{ij} = \phi(L)s_{it}   + \psi(L)u_{it},\qquad t=4,...,36\qquad i=1,...,n$$

where $\phi(L)$ and $\psi(L)$ are polynomials in the lag operator operating on $t$.

Comment: Yes, you have the setup correct. The data from period 1,2,3 can be used. The value at t=3 is the most important because sometimes it is only at that point that the account is funded, but not always. So, we could use the account balance at 1,2 and 3 or just use 3 but engineer features such as indicators if the balance increased from t=1 to t=2, for example. We also have covariates to use from all periods 1,2,3 for example, the total number of deposits made over that time.

Comment: For simplicity, you are correct that the effect of the time-invariant covariates do not change for each time t. It could by taking their interaction.

Comment: I need to research VARMA as I am not familiar, but why would you subtract the balance in the first 3 periods? S_it is not cumulative...

Comment: Is V ARMA "simply" a traditional ARMA model but stacking vectors of series? Does the fitting take into account all of the series or each independently?

Comment: Can you fit the models on historical data (t=1..36) and then apply it to new accounts that only have t=1..3?

Comment: I do wonder how different this approach is from using a neural net with lagged regressors https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/3 and then iteratively predicting new cases by using a one-step ahead forecast, using that forecast in the model to predict the next value and continuing until all 36 values are predicted.

Comment: VARMA permit interdependencies between the various equations comprising the system - is not just stacking unrelated equations. Yes you can have different estimation and forecasting horizons. Many estimation-prediction approaches exhibit similarities in various levels - in methodology and or results. But in general, one cannot tell a priori how different approaches will compare for a specific problem and data set.

Answer (score 2):

Your comment "Hence, this is a forecasting type problem, but not in the time series sense where you observe a sequence of data significantly longer than the time horizon you are trying to predict." causes me some concern. If I observe 3 numbers say 8,10,12 ... the "best model" to predict this stream for the next 33 periods would be an ARIMA/Transfer Function model with a causal predictor(t) of the form y(t)=6+2*t+a(t) . Thus to me it is a "typical time series forecasting problem" as there is no requirement (although it is a good suggestion) that the data used to develop a model is "longer" than the length of the prediction. As an aside a functionally equivalent representation is y(t)=y(t-1)+2+a(t) both yielding the same forecasts.

As new observations become available e.g. the four values 8,10,12,10 , the best that could be done would be to identify the last observation (value=10) as being an anomaly and the equation would remain the same as the one that was developed using the first three observations. In terms of generality,the "8" could be considered an anomaly to the pattern "10,12,10" which just illustrates the problem with small data sets. This ambiguity would go away as the observed sample got larger.

One of our classic time series is 1,9,1,9,1,9,1,9,5,9  where the "5" although near the mean is nowhere near the expected value of "1".

Combining both ARIMA( the general term ) and empirically detected exceptions (Pulses,Level/Step,Seasonal Pulses/Local Time Trends) can lead to useful models.

Comment: Are you suggesting the best way to model this would be to use an ARIMA on just the first three values (and the time-invariant covariates), which might be something like <0, 145.32, 132.76> for the three values and covariates such as number of other products the customer owns? Then do this for each account separately? So, you ignore the historical balance streams?

Comment: I dont know enough about time series modeling to know if it is possible to train the model using historical accounts (where the value at time t=1..36 is known) and then use it to predict t=4..36 values from new accounts where only t=1..3 is known. That is exactly the case I am looking for, but was not under the impression ARIMA would allow that...

Comment: @B_Miner What I had in mind is we know the average balance for periods 1-36 or reasonable expectations of these average balances (x1,x2,..x36).Let's call that x variable a covariate.Now we observe for a particular customer y1,y2 and y3. One can build a model between y and x exploiting whatever cross-correlative structure exists between y and x and any autoprojective structure evident in the lags of y.This might need augmentation using Pulses/Level/Step shifts,seasonal pulses.local tine trends reflecting omitted deterministic structure.THis is called a Dynamic Regression or a Transfer Function

Comment: In order to integrate causal structure , ARIMA structure and needed Intervention Series you might want to look at my comments http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72039/detecting-patterns-in-residual-plot/72055#72055 as they are relevant in forming the kinds of equations I am discussing.

Answer (score 1):

Going by your statement, you might want to look at Hidden Markov Modeling. The paper by [Paas et al](http://members.home.nl/jeroenvermunt/paas2006.pdf) will give you a good idea. For modeling the same, you can look at the depmixS4 package in R.

Some of your constraints might be that you can use only information till month 3 which will hurt your estimation.

Hope this helps. Would like to hear from you if I have not understood your problem correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the paper, looks interesting but i am not sure that is my situation - it appears from a quick glance that this is about predicting how customers purchase products over time - correct? My problem is about predicting the amount that will be in their account over discrete periods.